# Java: When to use checked exceptions, unchecked exceptions, or assertions

Tags: java, exception, assertions

I writing the following method:

```
public int count(int x){
 //method contents
}
```

The parameter x must be between 0 and 10, although anyone using this code wouldn't have an issue as anyone using this method would never have an x which does not fulfill the requirements.  Catching and handling checked exceptions could be a bit tedious due to the number of times the "count" method would be called. What is the best way to enforce x is always between 0 and 10: checked exception, unchecked exception, or assertion?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389127/checked-and-unchecked-exceptions-and-design-thoughts?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957645/when-to-use-an-assertion-and-when-to-use-an-exception?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070932/java-unchecked-checked-exception-clarification?rq=1 and many others.

Comment: also, just read Effective Java, 2nd ed by Joshua Bloch - chapter 9 explains this matter in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

- checked exceptions are definitely out of the question because they only make sense for events which can come about *regardless* of the validity of input<sup>1</sup>;
- an unchecked exception makes sense as a validation error: for example throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` would be by the book;
- Java assertions should only be used to assert method *invariants*, those that must hold whatever the input is. An assertion failure should mean that the "guilty part" is not the caller, but the method's code itself.

---

<sup>1</sup> Josh Bloch, Effective Java, Item 41:

> The burden [of checked exceptions] is justified if the exceptional condition cannot be prevented by proper use of the API *and* the programmer using the API can take some useful action once confronted with the exception. Unless both of these conditions hold, an unchecked exception is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on your style but the most common way would be an unchecked exception.

I would code something like this:

```
public int count(int x){
 if (x < 0 || x > 10) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(...);
 }
 //method contents
}
```

Comment: poor response, please elaborate more (eg: in design trade-offs, API exposure, testing).